# How to combine JS Objects with duplicate key/values

Tags: javascript

sorry if this is a easy question, I am just having a hard time trying to figure out how I would tackle this problem.

For example, I have 2 Objects as below:

```
cont oldCar = {
  model: 'Honda',
  notes: {
    id: 1,
    timestamp: 2000,
    text: 'is old'
  }
}

cont oldCar = {
  model: 'Toyota',
  notes: {
    id: 1,
    timestamp: 4000,
    text: 'is new'
  }
}
```

I want to try and combine the above two objects. I know they have same key's so I wanted to merge the values of each key if they are the same. Such as:

```
mode: 'Honda / Toyota'
```

I tried the following:

```
let merged = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

But this will merge both objects but it only retains the values from the right object. I was trying to do a for loop and add check if the key is same in both objects then combine the values together but I keep getting lost and it is hard to visualise. If someone could help me understand how i can create an for loop to start the comparison that would help me in completing the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this merge, perhaps you could do some array-reduce, it will also work with a list of unspecific size:

```
let array = Array(oldCar1,oldCar2)
let result = array.reduce((a,b)=> {
  let r = Object.assign({},a)
  r.notes = Object.assign({},r.notes)
  if (a.model != b.model) {
    r["model"] = a.model + " / " + b.model;
  }
  if (a.notes.text != b.notes.text) {
    r.notes.text = a.notes.text + " / " + b.notes.text;
  }
  // ...
  return r;
})
```

Comment: Ahh thank you very much. I will have to read up more of array-reduce. I will just play with this a bit more before marking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to achieve? Is it only the merging of `model` prop or something else?

Do you have more than two objects, is the amount of objects dynamic? If there are only two objects you can do that without any loops.

```
const merged = {
  model: `${firstCar.model} / ${secondCar.model}`,
  // etc...
};
```

But as I said before - if the amount of objects is not constant then you'd need a map that would:

- go through each car
- try and find a match by ID from other cars
- if there's a match return a merged result, if there's no match return the object as it is

Let me know what exactly are your needs here.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear enough, first time posting here.

As you mentioned what I want to learn is how to iterate through the key/value of only 2 Objects. If the Objects have the same Key then the Values should be merged as I mentioned above. There will always be 2 objects. How ever the amount of "notes" may be different for each object.